# systemd: nfs bg mount fails on boot

Tags: linux, systemd, nfs

I use the "bg" option in the fstab nfs mount entry as the nfs share is not always available upon boot of the computer:

```
sal.fritz.box:/tank1_data /mnt/sal_data nfs fsc,nfsvers=4.2,nofail,bg    0  0
```

This gets converted to the following systemd "mount" unit:

```
# /run/systemd/generator/mnt-sal_data.mount
# Automatically generated by systemd-fstab-generator

[Unit]
SourcePath=/etc/fstab
Documentation=man:fstab(5) man:systemd-fstab-generator(8)

[Mount]
Where=/mnt/sal_data
What=sal.fritz.box:/tank1_data
Type=nfs
TimeoutSec=infinity
Options=x-systemd.mount-timeout=infinity,retry=10000,fsc,nfsvers=4.2,nofail,bg,fg
```

What I do expect now is that upon boot the "mount" process waits until the nfs share becomes available. However, directly after booting the unit is indicated as failed:

```
● mnt-sal_data.mount - /mnt/sal_data
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/fstab; generated; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2020-10-29 23:18:27 CET; 3min 8s ago
    Where: /mnt/sal_data
     What: sal.fritz.box:/tank1_data
     Docs: man:fstab(5)
           man:systemd-fstab-generator(8)
    Tasks: 0
   CGroup: /system.slice/mnt-sal_data.mount

Okt 29 23:18:27 hal2000 systemd[1]: Mounting /mnt/sal_data...
Okt 29 23:18:27 hal2000 systemd[1]: mnt-sal_data.mount: Mount process exited, code=exited status=32
Okt 29 23:18:27 hal2000 systemd[1]: Failed to mount /mnt/sal_data.
Okt 29 23:18:27 hal2000 systemd[1]: mnt-sal_data.mount: Unit entered failed state.
```

Obviously, in this case the nfs share gets never mounted.
However, if I manually restart the mount unit everything works as expected: the mount process waits for the availability of the nfs share ...

```
● mnt-sal_data.mount - /mnt/sal_data
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/fstab; generated; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: activating (mounting) since Thu 2020-10-29 23:56:19 CET; 9s ago
[...]
  Process: 10713 ExecUnmount=/usr/bin/umount /mnt/sal_data -c (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
Cntrl PID: 10833 (mount)
    Tasks: 2
   CGroup: /system.slice/mnt-sal_data.mount
           ├─10833 /usr/bin/mount sal.fritz.box:/tank1_data /mnt/sal_data -t nfs -o x-systemd.mount-timeout=infinity,retry=10000,fsc,nf>
           └─10834 /sbin/mount.nfs sal.fritz.box:/tank1_data /mnt/sal_data -o rw,retry=10000,fsc,nfsvers=4.2,bg,fg

Okt 29 23:56:19 hal2000 systemd[1]: Mounting /mnt/sal_data...
```

... and as soon the share becomes available, it is sucessfully mounted:

```
● mnt-sal_data.mount - /mnt/sal_data
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/fstab; generated; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: active (mounted) since Thu 2020-10-29 23:59:44 CET; 5s ago
[...]
  Process: 10713 ExecUnmount=/usr/bin/umount /mnt/sal_data -c (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 10833 ExecMount=/usr/bin/mount sal.fritz.box:/tank1_data /mnt/sal_data -t nfs -o x-systemd.mount-timeout=infinity,retry=1000>
    Tasks: 0
   CGroup: /system.slice/mnt-sal_data.mount

Okt 29 23:56:19 hal2000 systemd[1]: Mounting /mnt/sal_data...
Okt 29 23:59:44 hal2000 systemd[1]: Mounted /mnt/sal_data.
```

I also changed the "nofail"-option: no difference. I expect that the manual restart is not required. What do I miss ?
I don't want to use the "automount"-feature as this results in a temporary system hang if the mount point is accidentally accessed.

System: openSUSE Leap 15.1, systemd 234

*Regards, Sven*

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you mean by automount causing a temporary system hang? From what I can gather, trying to fix your issue with things hanging seems to be more realistic than getting the mount unit to behave. I'm currently looking into this issue myself, but apart from processes waiting for the mount to become available, I'm not aware of anything hanging?